# How to set path between 2 points and make robot to take sensor data while moving on it?

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have created a basic world model with cylinders and boxes as obstacles. I am using Pioneer robot. I want to make a path between a start point and an end point (random points in the world) and want the robot to move on the path and get the sensor data. I was thinking to use Sonar data but I guess laser or IR would work too. I have no clue how to proceed and what to do.

I am trying implement Kalman Filter for Robot Localization. For that I need to get the data from the world, then add noise to it and then use Kalman filter to estimate the actual data from the noisy data. I am stuck at the very first step.

What shall I do to proceed ? Do I need to install ROS ? I have installed only Gazebo on my Ubuntu. Is that good enough ?

I am new to Gazebo and perhaps the only one to use Gazebo in my university. Please pardon me if my questions are very trivial and stupid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1374/how-to-set-path-between-2-points-and-make-robot-to-take-sensor-data-while-moving-on-it-?/) by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Well, to accomplish these tasks you need some lines of code...

I think that ROS/GazeboSim is the best alternative to accomplish these tasks. You will need to learn how to use path planning (deliberative navigation) and reactive navigation. There are some stacks in ROS that will facilitate your job. Take a look in motion planning (OMPL stack) and navigation stack [Motion planners](http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planners) and [Stack navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

If your environment is static, probably you know the "map" of environment and you can use a motion planning algorithm to compute the path between the two points. Once the path was planned the next step is execute the actions that will take the robot until the target. So you can collect data sensors using ros-enabled model plugins . Take a look: [Gazebo tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials) and [ROS-Enabled Plugins](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/ros_enabled_model_plugin)

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-02-14**:
Thanks Daniel,
I will try these and let you know if I have any problem.

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-15**:
Welcome to gazebo simulator and mobile robotics world!

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-03-22**:
@ Daniel Vaz : Hi Daniel, I went through the links you suggested. However, I still don't know how to move the robot from one point to another. Can you please tell me the best place where I can find the instructions for moving a pioneer robot ? Is there a code snippet I can look at to get an idea ? Please help. Thanks.

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-03-22**:
Try to follow the tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map

First learn what is doing with turtle bot, how and when things happens. After try to do it for Pioneer.

**Comment by [amit](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/166/amit/) on 2013-03-22**:
Thanks Daniel...

**Comment by [madhu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2924/madhu/) on 2016-11-24**:
Hello sir..I am also starting  to work on ros +gazebo,I am also need guidance ...how to interface an external camera with simulator? how to access external network camera access with gazebo and ros...? please I need guidance sir..kindly help me ..